# meaningless characters!

Tags: c#-4.0

I am writing a Persian RSS reader. for reading RSS, I use Chilkat free RSS component, but for some websites the output of the component is malformed and unreadable. I know this is a problem with encoding, but couldn't fix it by converting either utf8 or utf16.

Please note that for some websites it works correctly.

Because the component has nothing to set default encoding or locale, can someone help me fix the issue?

Example:

Original value in the RSS xml file: Tabnak.IR | تابناك

Program output: Tabnak.IR | ØªØ§Ø¨Ù†Ø§Ùƒ

I am using .Net 4 and C#

Comment: You will need to provide more information about how you are using the component (sample code) as well as explain where and how are you trying to output the text.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that the component doesn't have anything to do with it. Could you give us some more data? (a simplified case etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another component RSS.Net that is also free and works well.

sample of my previous code could be found here: 
http://www.example-code.com/csharp/rss_read_feed.asp